# How to suppress su authentication failure warning?

Tags: debian, users, su

I created an account "`diag`" and set it as expired (`usermod --expiredate 1`). Then I have a script which I want to run to log into it, so in the script I use the following command:

```
su -s /bin/bash - diag
```

This outputs like so:

```
Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator
su: Authentication failure
(Ignored)
diag@computer:~$
```

And then I'm able to use the account, as expected.

I want to suppress the first three lines, the warning about the expired account. I tried adding `2> /dev/null` to the end of the command, but that suppresses all the output from bash; I just get a blank response, and I can type commands into it and see the result from them, but I see no bash prompt. I tried adding just `> /dev/null` and that does nothing.

So I've deduced that apparently `su` is piping all its output over `stderr`. How can I get `su` to just suppress those first three lines, but otherwise act normally as if the account weren't expired?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Beware the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I am trying to open a bash prompt for an expired user.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, user account expiration and lock is functionally the same thing; login attempts will fail, SSH attempts will fail, etc. At least for my purposes they are the same.

So, in my script, I now detect whether the user is expired, and if so, lock the user and set the expiration to 'never'.

It looks something like this:

```
# Takes 1 parameter, the username to check
# Returns 0 if the user is expired, or 1 if it is not expired.
function userExpired()
{
    # These day values are just numbers, the number of days since the epoch.
    local expireDay=`grep $1 /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f8`

    # If diag has no expiration date, it will be empty.
    if [[ "$expireDay" -eq "" ]] ; then
        return 1
    fi

    local today=`perl -e 'print int(time/(60*60*24))'`
    local daysUntilExpire=`echo $expireDay - $today | bc`

    [[ $daysUntilExpire -lt 0 ]]
}

# Check if the diag user is expired and if so, lock and unexpire it.
userExpired diag && {
    usermod --lock --expiredate -1 diag
}
```

I wrote the userExpired function from code found in [this forum post](http://www.unix.com/302598617-post1.html) (modified to fit my code style and better variable naming).

Comment: Caution: --lock and --expiredate are subtly different. Lock prevents password login (typically by prepending ! to the password hash in the passwd or shadow file) but a user who previously established SSH keys (for example) will still be able to gain access. In this case, this is unlikely, since your `diag` user has been custom made, but I note this here for completeness. The expiredate approach is still the recommended approach if you truly want to disable login, but still allow `su` and friends to work.

Answer (score 0):

Redirected stderr to stdout

```
su -s /bin/bash - diag 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

---

This one I haven't tried but expect should work (will update soon once home)

```
discard=$(su -s /bin/bash - diag)
```

Comment: How does this differ from simply redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` with `2> /dev/null`?

Comment: `that wont suppress all the output from bash` ;) , however I havent tested these, I would appreciate if you can tell what you observed...

Comment: I think we're having a misunderstanding. I don't want all output suppressed; I just want the `su` expiration warning to not be displayed.