# Why `su` gives "su: Authentication failure" even when running as root?

Tags: authentication, su

Somewhat like in [How to suppress su authentication failure warning?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49931/how-to-suppress-su-authentication-failure-warning), but it actually does not run the command at all.

```
# su limited
su: Authentication failure
# su -s /bin/bash limited
su: Authentication failure
# su -s /bin/bash - limited
su: Authentication failure
```

Why does it bother to check authentication when being run from root?

---

For most users `su` does work normally.

```
# grep limited /etc/passwd
limited:x:1001:1001::/home/limited:/bin/bash
# grep limited /etc/shadow
#
```

Being missing from `/etc/shadow` does not prevent most other users from being `su`-ed into.

I see log entry when I try:

```
Apr 21 10:43:18 thehostname su: FAILED SU (to limited) root on pts/110
```

```
# egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/pam.d/su
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session    optional   pam_mail.so nopen
session    required   pam_limits.so
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

Comment: Does the host in question have any non-standard PAM configuration?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, I don't remember setting it up. For most other users `su` does work normally.

Comment: How did you create the `limited` user? AFAIK, there ought to be an entry for it in the `shadow` file.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I don't remember, it was long ago. There are 95 entries in `/etc/shadow` and 157 entries in `/etc/passwd`, but for most other users that are missing from shadow `su $USERNAME` is working like it should.

Comment: What does `egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/pam.d/su` say? (edit it into your Q)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an `x` in the (mostly obsolete) password field of `/etc/passwd`. According to `man 5 passwd` (on my Debian/Raspbian machines as well as [online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5@@shadow-utils.html)) this means that there *must* be a corresponding entry in `/etc/shadow`:

> If the password field is a lower-case “x”, then the encrypted password is actually stored in the shadow(5) file instead; there must be a corresponding line in the `/etc/shadow file`, or else the user account is invalid.

I suspect that you're hitting that last clause, "*the user account is invalid*", and `su` is erring on the side of caution.

Example (Raspbian), with all commands run as root

```
grep test.: /etc/passwd
test1:x:1005:1005:Test 1:/home/test1:/bin/bash
test2:x:1006:1006:Test 2:/home/test2:/bin/bash

grep test.: /etc/shadow
test1:!:18373:0:99999:7:::

su test1 -c id
uid=1005(test1) gid=1005(test1) groups=1005(test1)

su test2 -c id
su: Authentication failure
```

The solution appears to be either not to use `x` in the `passwd` password field or to add corresponding entries in `/etc/shadow`. (Note that making the password field in `/etc/passwd` empty will probably allow the user to log in without a password. Instead, use `!`, which will mark the account as locked.)

You should be able to use the `pwconv` command to fix up the `/etc/shadow` file with the missing entries.

Comment: but according to the OP, this works with other users (admittedly, that may be a user mistake, I was not able to reproduce it)

Comment: Yes, removing `x` from the `/etc/passwd` line made `su` work again. Why there was no specific error message neither in console nor in auth log?

Comment: @Vi. removing the `x` will let anybody login as that user without any password (at least from console, Ctrl-Alt-F3 and enter the user name; ssh or su may be more fastidious and refuse to accept it). Don't do that. It's a bad idea to mess with that stuff by hand. __NB__ On a vanilla Debian 10, `su` will not complain, and let anybody become a user, if that user has an empty password field in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Indeed. `pwconv` resolved the issues.